# LINQ: Sum() of distinct Elements

Tags: c#, linq

Given the following list:

```
(TABLE1)
Expedient Amount 
1         10
1         10 
2         3
2         3
3         4
```

I want to calculate the sum of 'Amount' of different Expedients. So the total sum should be:

```
10 (from Expedient 1) + 
 3 (from Expediente 2) + 
 4 (from Expedient 3) = 
10 + 3 + 4 = 17
```

Something similar to this SQL sentence:

```
Select SUM(Amount) from 
(Select Distinct Expedient, Amount from TABLE1) DummyTable
```

Comment: Please show the relevant C# code and your model class

Comment: what do you do if you have different `Amount` numbers for the same `Expedient`? how do you choose?

Comment: No Master-Detail here, Expedient has always same Amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spender's solution is spot on. If you like to go a tad more compact (that's what LINQ is), use this overload of `GroupBy`:

```
Table1.GroupBy(t => new {t.Expedient, t.Amount}, (t, g) => g.First()).Sum(g => g.Amount)
```

Answer (score 6):

Off the top of my head, something like this should do the trick:

```
TABLE1
    .GroupBy(t => new {t.Expedient, t.Amount})
    .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
    .Sum(item => item.Amount);
```

Comment: `GroupBy()` has an overload that takes two selectors which will make it shorter.

Comment: Also `Sum()` can take a selector too.

Comment: `TABLE1.GroupBy(t => new {t.Expedient, t.Amount}, t2 => t2.Amount).Sum()` should do.

Comment: @dotNET Do you mean something like .GroupBy(t => new {t.Expedient, t.Amount}).Sum( x => x.FirstOrDefault().Amount);?

Comment: @Txaran: See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try Code:

```
 var result = (from p in tabledetails.AsEnumerable()
                      group p by p.id into jj
                      select new table1
                      {
                          id = jj.FirstOrDefault().id,
                          value = jj.ToList().Max(c => c.value)
                      }).ToList().Sum(c => c.value);
```